# ¿Como colocar un numeral en un datagridview?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

Como colocar dentro de una **columna** de un `datagridview` **números consecutivos**, que cada que se cree un registro se vaya agregando números, si creo un registro y es el primero me coloque **1**, si es el segundo me coloque **2**... Y que cuando se ordene por una columna en desde el `datagridview` estos numeros se muevan con su respectivo registro. Y que si se elimina uno, se vuelva a **reordenar**, 1,2,3,4... No quiero que los números vengan desde la base de datos, solo lo quiero para la vista, esto no es un id para identificar el registro es solo para la parte visual.

Aquí el código que uso:

```
private void dgvProveedor_CellValueNeeded(object sender, DataGridViewCellValueEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex == ColumnIdNumeral.Index)
   {
       e.Value = e.RowIndex + 1;
   }
}
```

Este código así como está funciona (no he probado lo de eliminar) pero cada que se ingresa un registro se me suma 1, el problema radica en que cuando ordeno por una columna del `datagridview` los números no se mueven, se quedan estáticos, hay una manera de que se muevan con el registro?

para insertar utilizo esto en un boton:

```
private void btnGuardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {     
    string codProd = txtCodigoProd.Text.Trim();
    txtNombreProd.Text = txtNombreProd.Text.ToUpper();
    string nombreProd = txtNombreProd.Text.Trim();
    string descrip = txtDescripcionProd.Text.Trim();
    string stock = txtStockProd.Text.Trim();
    string costo = txtCostoProd.Text.Trim();
    costo = costo.Replace(".", ",");
    string precVenta = txtPrecio1PublicoProd.Text.Trim();
    precVenta = precVenta.Replace(".", ",");
    string prec2 = txtPrecio2Prod.Text.Trim();
    prec2 = prec2.Replace(".", ",");
    string prec3 = txtPrecio3Prod.Text.Trim();
    prec3 = prec3.Replace(".", ",");
    string medidas = cmbMedidasProd.SelectedValue.ToString().Trim();
    string prov = cmbProveedor.SelectedValue.ToString().Trim();
    mProductos.InsertarProd(nombreProd, codProd, descrip, medidas, stock, costo, precVenta, prec2, prec3, prov, idempresaM);
}
```

Y mi daragridview lo lleno asi:

```
private void CargarProductosMenuAdmin()
{
   dgvProductos.DataSource = mProductos.RecogerDatosProd(idempresaM);
}
```

Destaco que cuando se inicia la aplicacion por primera vez el `datagrid` esta vacio, por eso el codigo para insertar, al insertar se me actualiza y me muestra los datos, el **IdEmpresaM** es una condicion `Where` que esta en mi `Sql`

Comment: Coloca algo de codigo que hayas realizado.

Comment: @RamiroBarone listo, olvide colocarlo

Comment: yo agregaria una propiedad al modelo de datos tuyo, y cada vez que lo borro o agrego un registro reordeno todo, y cuando reeordenes por otra columna se mueve en conjunto.

Comment: @RamiroBarone me podrías dar un ejemplo, no sabría como hacerlo

Comment: agregar tu clase al codigo.

Comment: @RamiroBarone cual clase? ese codigo esta en mi formulario, donde esta el datagridview, las columnas estan hechas en modo diseño, me puedes indicar que codigo quieres que agregue?

Answer (score 0):

A modo de ejemplo para que entiendas el concepto, te cree una clase, y 3 metodos. Uno para cargar tu gridview, otro para agregar una persona y ordenar los numeros y otra para borrar una persona y ordenar los numeros.

```
    ObservableCollection<Producto> productos = new ObservableCollection<Producto>();

    private void CargarGrilla()
    {
        ///Rellenar tu List desde el storeProcedure
        ///


        /// rellenas tu datagridview

        dgvProveedor.DataSource = productos;

    }
    public void AgregarProductoClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Posible evento click que tengas para aceptar la carga de una persona
        int contador = 1;
        // Deberias rellenar las propiedades desde un textbox o el mismo gridView

        productos.Add(new Producto{ Descrip = "TxtDescripcion", codProd = "23132156" });

        //reordenar
        foreach (var item in productos)
        {
            item.NumeroColumn = contador;
            contador++;
        }

        dgvProveedor.DataSource = productos;
    }
    public void BorrarProductoClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Posible evento click que tengas para aceptar el borrado de una persona
        int contador = 1;
        // Deberias rellenar las propiedades desde un textbox o el mismo gridView

        Producto producto= new Producto{ prod = "tutxt", codProd = "123132" };
        //Borramos la producto del listado
        productos.Remove(producto);

        //reordenar
        foreach (var item in productos)
        {
            item.NumeroColumn = contador;
            contador++;
        }
        dgvProveedor.DataSource = productos;
    }

}
//Clase de ejemplo

public class Producto
{
    public int codProd { get; set; }
    public int nombreProd { get; set; }
    public string descrip { get; set; }
    public string stock { get; set; }
    public string costo { get; set; }
    public string precVenta { get; set; }
    public string prec2 { get; set; }
    public string prec3 { get; set; }
    public string medidas { get; set; }
    public string prov { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: okey, pero hay agregaste como una coleccion, yo agrego los datos mediante un codigo insert, agarro los datos de un textbox, y los paso al insert

Comment: cual es tu codigo insert?

Comment: creo que ya te coloque todo el código necesario, no se si faltaria algo mas

Comment: mProductos.InsertarProd(nombreProd, codProd, descrip, medidas, stock, costo, precVenta, prec2, prec3, prov, idempresaM); este metodo rellena un List o Array?

Comment: Esos variables que van a los parámetros del procedimiento almacenado, utilizo un procedimiento almacenado para insertar, y las columnas del datagrid están creadas en modo diseño dónde su **DataPropertyName** son las columnas de la base de datos

Comment: Entonces tomando como ejemplo mi respuesta y adaptarla tu solucion deberias agregar una clase para manejar los objetos y actualizaciones, luego pasas ese objeto creado a tu procedimiento almacenado.

Comment: Okey pero el procedimiento almacenado es para insertar registros, lo del numeral es solo para la vista

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105991/discussion-between-ramiro-barone-and-nathy).